# Show DialogFragment in ActionBar.Tab fragments

Tags: android, android-tabs, android-dialogfragment

I have a few Actiobar with 5 tabs each with a fragment. In 3 of this fragments I want to show a Dialog so I've created a new class:

```
 public static class MyDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
        static MyDialogFragment newInstance() {
            return new MyDialogFragment();
        }

        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            int style = DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL;
            int theme =  android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Dialog;

            setStyle(style, theme);
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dialog, container, false);
            View tv = v.findViewById(R.id.textV);
            ((TextView)tv).setText("Dialog using style Normal - Theme AlertDialog - NoActionBar");


            return v;
        }
    }
```

In every onCreate method of this 3 fragments I'm trying to show the Dialog by using this method:

```
private void showPopup()
{
    FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    Fragment prev = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("dialog");
    if (prev != null) {
        ft.remove(prev);
    }
    ft.addToBackStack(null);

    DialogFragment newFragment = MyDialogFragment.newInstance();
    newFragment.show(ft, "dialog");

}
```

Now the problem is that this dialog is displayed on tabs that should not.

For example I want tabs 1 3 and 5 to display the Dialog  - and sometimes it displays it - but sometimes when I tap the tab 2 this dialog appears and if I tap 3 the Dialog is not showed.
What could be the problem and how should I fix it? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you try to move your showPopup() call in onCreateView() or in onActivityCreated() methods, instead of in onCreate() one ?

EDIT: According to comments below, the problem is linked to the use of a ViewPager, which prepare some next Fragments to be viewed, and then call onCreate() methods.

Comment: I've tried to add showPopup() in onCreateView() but the way the Dialog appears is quite random. I can figure it out why?

Comment: Do you notice some change ?

Comment: right now it seems that the popup is showed twice - for example the popup in 3 and 5 is showed when I click tab 2 - but this is not the behaviour everytime

Comment: Wow, this behavior is really weird :/ There no way that one Fragment can show the DialogFragment declared in another Fragment...

Comment: It seems there is - and I think I found what is the problem. Basically when I click on Tab 2 - the view pager starts and creates an instance of tab 1 and tab 3 I guess... so that when the user wants to navigate to the next tab - some elements are in place...so that's why my method was called - even if I wasn't on the right tab!

Comment: I've tried to add the showPopup() method in onStart an onResume hopping that this method will be called only when the fragment will be visible...but no luck

Comment: Oooooh, you use ViewPager !!! It change everything. Do you use FragmentPagerAdapter or FragmentStatePagerAdapter ?

Comment: FragmentStatePagerAdapter why does it matter?

Comment: Anyway, using [setOffscreenPageLimit(0)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setOffscreenPageLimit%28int%29) on the ViewPager may be fix the problem.

Comment: By default, ViewPager prepare the 2 Fragment to each side of the showing one. This is why onCreate() of Fragment 3 is called when you show Fragment 2 from the Fragment 1 (for exemple).

Comment: setOffscreenPageLimit(0) needs a default value of 1

Comment: Arf... Such a great doc as usual. At this point, I see one solution : use a listener in the host Activity. Maybe the [ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener.html) ?

Comment: I've managed to find a solution - in every fragment I override a method called setMenuVisibility - and test if the the fragment is visible. If it is - I call my method.

Answer (score 0):

So I've found a solution - in every fragment I override a method called setMenuVisibility - and test if the the fragment is visible. If it is - I call my method.